# Aggregate and Group by over 15 second using c# linq

Tags: c#, .net

I have following datatable;

```
SAMPLE_TIME    CPU
-----------------------------
14:59:32       3
14:59:20       2
14:59:14       9    
14:58:57       2
14:58:48       1
```

What i want is, summing "count" over 15 second intervals and getting average to new datatable.

So, I want to get the following result using linq;

```
SAMPLE_TIME     CPU
-----------------------------
14:59:32        0.33
14:59:17        0.6    
14:59:02        0.2
```

I tried to get it like below but i can't find the way;

```
        dtTA = (from dr1 in dtTA.AsEnumerable()
                group dr1 by dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") into g
                select new
                {
                    ST = g.Key,
                    CPU = g.Sum(h => h.Field<double>("CPU")),
                }).ToDataTable();
```

What should i change on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which truncates DateTimes to 15 seconds precision.

```
private static DateTime By15Seconds(DateTime d)
{
    long fifteenSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15).Ticks;
    return new DateTime((d.Ticks / fifteenSeconds) * fifteenSeconds);
}
```

Then use it like this

```
dtTA = (from dr1 in dtTA.AsEnumerable()
        group dr1 by By15Seconds(dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")) into g
        select new {
            ST = g.Key,
            CPU = g.Sum(h => h.Field<double>("CPU")) / 15.0,
        }).ToDataTable();
```

Note: This creates 15 seconds blocks starting at 00:00:00. If you want another start value for the seconds, you can first subtract this value, do the truncation and finally re-add this value. this is done in this generalized extension method:

```
public static DateTime BySeconds(this DateTime d, int blockSize, int startAt = 0)
{
    long blockTicks = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(blockSize).Ticks;
    long startTicks = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(startAt).Ticks;
    return new DateTime(((d.Ticks - startTicks) / blockTicks * blockTicks) + startTicks);
}
```